# Zariski dense subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $\Delta$ be a Zariski dense finitely generated subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$. Assume that $\Delta$ contains no element of finite order. Then, does there exist a  finite-order element $A \in SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ such that the group generated by all the elements of $\Delta$ and $A$ contains $\Delta$ as a finite index subgroup? We assume that $A$ is not an identity.

Is there some known conditions for $\Delta$ that the above statement holds?

Comment: This is already false for Fuchsian subgroups of $SL(2,R)$ (extended by $-I$). If you take holonomy of a generic convex real projective structure on a closed hyperbolic surface, you get $SL(3,R)$ examples.  

Comment: Let $\Delta$ be a holonomy groups of a convex real projective structure on some closed hyperbolic surface. Suppose that there is a finite-order element $A$ that makes the above statement holds. Then must the group generated by $\Delta$ and $A$ be a holonomy group of a convex real projective structure on some hyperbolic orbifold? 

Comment: Yes, of course. The point is that a finite index extension of a discrete group of projective transformations of a convex domain is still discrete. 